# $d(n)$ is odd iff $n = k^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, divisor-counting-function

The function $d(n)$ gives the number of positive divisors of $n$, including $n$ itself.
For example, $d(25) = 3$ because $25$ has three divisors: $1$, $5$, and $25$.
Prove that $d(n)$ is odd if and only if $n$ is a perfect square. I need to prove this by proving that $d(n)$ is odd if and only if $n = k^2$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: Hint: For every divisor $a$ of $n$, there is another related divisor, $n/a$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, but how does it take n=k^2 into account

Comment: Um, what? @Megan The quest is exactly the same. "A number is a perfect square" iff $n=k^2$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I know, but I need to prove that it is n=k^2 first. Does that prove it?

Comment: It's unclear if you are quibbling whether the question is a duplicate, or you are asking me to answer this duplicate question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I would like you to answer it please.

Comment: Ah, a commenter is not an answerer. And the whole point of marking questions as duplicates is to avoid adding the same answers over and over again to repeated questions. I've seen this particular question asked here several times recently.

Answer (score 0):

S'pose $n$ is not a square; then if $n = pq$, you know that $p$ and $q$ are different (can you explain why?). So divisors of $n$ come in pairs (any divisor $p$ is paired with $n/p$), hence there are an even number of them. Now see if you can do the other case.